# Series in Probability.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

I'm working on a problem which has a bit like

$^{(1)}P(\Sigma_{i\in N}A_i=1)$

where the sequence $A_i\in\{0,1\}, i\in N$, also independent.

$^{(2)}P(A_i=1)=\frac{2}{3i+2}$

How can I simplify $(1)$?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question statement correctly, we have $A_i$ as mutually independent Bernoulli trails with the chance of success  $p_i =  \frac2{3 i + 2}$ 
 for $A_i = 1$. In other words, the chance of $A_i = 0$ is $q_i  = 1 - p_i = \frac{3i}{ 3i + 2}$.

Your notation is a bit unclear in that whether $N$ means a general finite integer or $\mathbb{N}$ the entire set of countably infinite integers.

Anyway, let's consider $i = 1,2,\ldots, n$ for a finite $n$.

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}_n \equiv P\left( \sum_{i = 1}^n A_i = 1 \right) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left[ P(A_i = 1)  \prod_{j \neq i} P(A_j = 0) \right] \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left[ \frac2{3i + 2}  \prod_{j \neq i} \frac{ 3i }{3i + 2} \right] \\
&= \frac23 \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac53)}  H_n
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(k)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which equals $(k-1)!$ for integer $k$, and $H_n$ is the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

At the limit of $n \to \infty$ to cover all the natural numbers, it can be shown that $\mathcal{P}_n \to 0$.

Actually, if all you care is the $i \in \mathbb{N}$ case with all natural numbers, right off the bat we know the desired probability is zero $P\left( \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} } A_i = 1 \right) =  0$.

This is because they sum to $1$ but only one of the $A_i$ get to be one and all the infinitely many others has to be zero. The product of infinitely many such $q_i = \frac{3i}{3i+2} < 1$ is trivially zero.

Comment: N is the set of (all +ve) integers, I didn't know TeX for that sorry. But doesn't Borel Cantelli come into play? My $(1)$ is to "show it is equal to 1".

Comment: Which event are you really considering in (1)? The way you typed it with the "${}=1$" inside reads as:  $\{ \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} } A_i = 1 \}$ that the event which they sum to unity. The individual $A_i$ themselves are not events the way you described them, nor is $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N} } A_i $ an event.

Comment: This is exactly the way the question in my notes were written. Show $P(\Sigma_{i \in N} A_i =1)=1$ and gives a clue to use Borel Cantella.

Comment: How are $A_i$ defined exactly then? Indeed in measure-theoretic treatment we often use $A_i$ to denote events, but here in (2) your $A_i$ are clearly Beroulli trials. Are these just separate questions or what? Did you mean to type  $A_i \in [0,1]$ or is it really just two elements $\{ 0, 1 \}$?

Comment: It also says exactly $A_i$ is $\{ 0,1 \}$ variabled, independent sequence. They arent separate no and no further information is given. I'll have to confront this one then.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a typo in the question. Since $\sum P\{A_i=1\} =\sum_i \frac 2 {3i+2} =\infty$ it follows by Borel Cantelli Lemma that with probability $1$, infinitley many $A_i$'s are equal to $1$. Hence $P\{\sum_i A_i=\infty\}=1$.